# java spring boot, how to write a test to check send request

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

Can someone please, tell me how you can write a test. I now have to test sending a request from one server to another using `RestTemplate`.

```
class ServiceTest {

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

@InjectMocks
private RConsumerService refundConsumerService = new RConsumerService(new RestTemplateBuilder());

@Test
public void sendRequestToBillingService(){
    ChargeResponse chargeResponse = new ChargeResponse();
    chargeResponse.setInstanceKey("testInstanceKey");

    KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = new KafkaMessage();
    kafkaMessage.setApplication_id(1L);
    kafkaMessage.setCompany_id(1111);
    TransactionRequestContext reqContext = refundConsumerService.createTxnRequestContext(kafkaMessage);

    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.any()
            , refundConsumerService.buildChargeRequest(reqContext), ChargeResponse.class))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(chargeResponse, HttpStatus.OK));

    refundConsumerService.refund(kafkaMessage);
    assertEquals(chargeResponse.getInstanceKey(), "testInstanceKey");
}
```

}

How do I write the condition correctly in

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.any()
            , refundConsumerService.buildChargeRequest(reqContext), ChargeResponse.class))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(chargeResponse, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Now I am getting this exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is required`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`, you don't need to create `new` instance of those objects. `Mockito` will inject it for you. I guess you have this exception because of this parameter : `Mockito.any()` in your `Mockito.when()`. It have to be of a `Uri` type.

Your code will looks like this :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private RConsumerService refundConsumerService;

    @Test
    public void sendRequestToBillingService() {
        ChargeResponse chargeResponse = new ChargeResponse();
        chargeResponse.setInstanceKey("testInstanceKey");

        KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = new KafkaMessage();
        kafkaMessage.setApplication_id(1L);
        kafkaMessage.setCompany_id(1111);
        TransactionRequestContext reqContext = refundConsumerService.createTxnRequestContext(kafkaMessage);

        URI mockUri = URI.create("http://localhost/mockUri");
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(mockUri
                        , refundConsumerService.buildChargeRequest(reqContext), ChargeResponse.class))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(chargeResponse, HttpStatus.OK));

        refundConsumerService.refund(kafkaMessage);
        assertEquals(chargeResponse.getInstanceKey(), "testInstanceKey");
    }

}
```